# Why navigation drawer is not working with my project?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new android programmer and i have a little project to make dashboard with navigation drawer, here is my code, need help. tq

**Modern Dashboard**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class ModernAcivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CardView cardView1,cardView2,cardView3,cardView4,cardView5;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.modern_dashboard);
        /*------slider------- */
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.menu_toolbar);
        /*------toolbar------- */
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        /*------navigation------- */
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        cardView1 =(CardView)findViewById(R.id.card1);
        cardView2 =(CardView)findViewById(R.id.card2);
        cardView3 =(CardView)findViewById(R.id.card3);
        cardView4 =(CardView)findViewById(R.id.card4);
        cardView5 =(CardView)findViewById(R.id.card5);

        cardView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ModernAcivity.this,InfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        cardView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ModernAcivity.this,KuesActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
        });
        cardView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ModernAcivity.this,ReportActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
             }
        });
        cardView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ModernAcivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
        });
        cardView5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ModernAcivity.this,VidioActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
        });

    }

}
```

I am doing a project in the android studio, and I need a navigation drawer, I made a navigation but the problem I can't slide it left and right its block without moving.

**Here is the layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/menu_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:navigationIcon="@mipmap/menu" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
        android:text="Sadari"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
        android:text="Periksa Payudara Sendiri"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/pita" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/card1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/informasi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                    android:text="Informasi"

                    android:textSize="18sp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/info"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ceksadari"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image2"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                    android:text="Cek Sadari"

                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/cek" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/card3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/laporanku"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                    android:text="Laporanku"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image3"
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/report" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/card4"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pengingat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image4"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                    android:text="Pengingat"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image4"
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/reminder" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/card5"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/videoku"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image5"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
                    android:text="Video"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image5"
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/video" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try putting `NavigationView` last in the `DrawerLayout` and setting `android:layout_gravity="start"` on it.

Comment: yeay, it's work..Thank you Nicolas